# What makes the looping index in \foreach produce compile-time error?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

Consider the following code and error message.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\psset{saveNodeCoors}
\degrees[13]
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(4,4)
\foreach \x [count=\xi from 0] in {A,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,T,J,Q,K}
{
    \pnodes(!3 \xi\space neg \pst@angleunit 90 add PtoC){X\x}
    \qdisk(X\x){1pt}
    \uput[!N-X\x.y N-X\x.x atan 1 \pst@angleunit div](X\x){\x}
    %\uput[!\the\psLoopIndex\space neg 90 1 \pst@angleunit div add ](X\x){\x}
}
\psarcn{->}(0,0){2.8}{(XA)}{(XQ)}
\end{pspicture}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

[image]

What makes the looping index in `\foreach` produce compile-time error? How to solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\usepackage{pgfmath}` that defines `\pgfmathparse` needs to be specified, because package `pgffor` is missing this dependency.

Comment: I raised that issue on the `tikz` issue tracker. Apparently, `pgfmath` gets automatically loaded with `pgffor` in the development version of `tikz`.